# Waterproofing a cat5e/6 repair

Tags: poe, waterproof, underwater, long-distance

I have a 1200 foot long outdoor direct burial network cable running through an outdoor environment that ranges from dry to 6+ ft underwater depending on the year and season. (Currently it is a foot or two underwater.) Something has severed the wire. What is the best way to repair the break while retaining the ability for the cable to be submerged for months at a time.

The cable does have POE running through it via a Veracity Longspan pair if that changes anything.

Comment: Best way? Run a new cable.

Comment: If water has got into the cut ends, there's no way you can dry it out adequately again before sealing it up. You need fresh cable.

Comment: If its not cut or rodent proof, you better put it inside a conduit like PVC. Leakage will occur eventually.. Start over.

Comment: It is a 1,200+ ft run. I was hoping for a less painful way to fix the problem. :-(

Comment: Is it cable designed for outdoor use, or direct burial, or ...? As per my answer - it may be fixable. But YMMV. I'd try it :-).

Comment: It is designed for both outdoor use and direct burial. Thank you much for your detailed answer. I will be giving it a shot

Comment: [Adhesive lined heatshrink tubing](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=ALeKk00i_PB22AIB480YxEteNiTAJ-IfzQ%3A1593758613069&ei=ldP-XqbiA8_w9QPXjbqYDA&q=%22adhesive+lined%22+heat+shrink&oq=%22adhesive+lined%22+heat+shrink&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeOgQIABBHOgIIAFCRlQJY_LECYKa1AmgAcAJ4AIAB6wKIAccRkgEFMi01LjOYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjmgPW_vbDqAhVPeH0KHdeGDsMQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) as per my answer. Brand quality will vary - suitability left to your assessment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have noted - repair is not a good choice if re-running is not a very unacceptable option.

Water will have run back inside the sheath and drying out would be hard and time consuming. Water may affect the characteristics - but maybe not enough to matter to you. ie it MAY be possible to operate the cable with a small amount of water inside the sheath. Or not.

Joints can be made using good soldering techniques and [adhesive lined heatshrink sleeving](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=ALeKk00i_PB22AIB480YxEteNiTAJ-IfzQ%3A1593758613069&ei=ldP-XqbiA8_w9QPXjbqYDA&q=%22adhesive+lined%22+heat+shrink&oq=%22adhesive+lined%22+heat+shrink&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeOgQIABBHOgIIAFCRlQJY_LECYKa1AmgAcAJ4AIAB6wKIAccRkgEFMi01LjOYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjmgPW_vbDqAhVPeH0KHdeGDsMQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) - not just standard heatshrink where water will travel along under the sheath with ease.
Then an over-layer of heat-shrink with adhesive over all wires and existing sheath.
Obviously the order of adding the unshrunk heatshrink sleeves needs thinking about in advance :-).

If you can bring the joint to an above ground housing so much the better. Above the water table is better than below and above ground better again.

Neutral cure good quality silicone rubber in addition to the over sleeve of heatshrink will improve chances of success. Adding some moisture absorbing compound inside the seal MAY help but you don't want something that can re-release water.

Corrosion is caused by metal-water-oxygen reaction. Water vapour will in time penetrate any flexible material known to a significant extent. Glass and metals less so - but they are not useful here. Eliminating liquid water so that there is only water vapour at the joint surface very very greatly eliminates corrosion rate. This requires a low water solubility compound around the wires and a void free contact between sealing compound and metal - that is in part what the heatshrink adhesive fill is for. Other compounds could be applied over the join inside the heatshrink adhesive seal. Sylgard 184 - intended for PV panel encapsulation MAY work. As may Dow Corning (maybe now rebranded) 1-2577 conformal coating.

Underwater cable ideally requires the use of underwater cable.
Cable "severed by something" ideally needs a something-proof cover - a conduit makes sense or failing that a dig proof layer - rock / gravel / slab or whatever

Comment: I can vouch for the adhesive-lined heatshrink - used it successfully under water at >120m depth. But you need to ensure that the cable jacket material is compatible with the adhesive.